# Can I use one definition of two Button by switching between them?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this two ImageButton views redButton and blueButton 
but in the code i used just one definition

```
ImageButton GButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
```

Then in the `clickListener` I have this code:

```
GButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.blueButton):
                GButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redButton);
            break;

            case (R.id.redButton):
                GButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I want the `clickListener` to switch to the `redButton`. But it doesn't.

Comment: why don't you just change background color of your blue button to red onClick?

Comment: No there is more code in the click event , not for color only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

Yes you can use one definition of two Button by switching between them.

Problem:

Your code is not working because **you haven't set clickListener after switching id's** of `GButton`.

Do it like this and it will start working:

```
GButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.blueButton):
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redButton);

                //ADD IT HERE

                GButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            break;

            case (R.id.redButton):
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                GButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);

                //ADD IT HERE

                GButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            break;
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: my pleasure happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use via setTag() method and check new tag in onClick through getTag() method.

There is another suggestion of `ViewFlipper` to switching between one to another.

Here is the example of it:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper">
    <RelativeLayout>
        // Red Button
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        // Green Button
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick` method you should reset the views `setOnClickListener` method

Answer (score 0):

please use this code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton btnRed, btnBlue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnBlue = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_blue);
    btnRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
    btnBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.btn_blue):
            //TODO handle blue ImageButton click
            break;
        case (R.id.btn_red):
            //TODO handle red ImageButton click
            break;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: he is asking to switch the definitions not how to define onclick..!!